# Does not respond to call to function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

```
  <button type="button" class="btn tblActnBtn" onclick="UpdateExpnse(id= <%#Eval("ExpenseID") %>  id2= <%#Eval("CustomerID") %>)" >
            <script>
   function UpdateExpnse(id, id2) {
                var Prod;
                var Classif;
              $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/Expense/" + id + "/ "+ id2,

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        Expense = JSON.parse(data);
                        $("#ExpenseID").val(Expense.ExpenseID);
                        $("#ExpenseName").val(Expense.ExpenseName);
                        $("#Date").val(Expense.Date);
                        $("#ActualDate").val(Expense.ActualDate);
                        $("#Amount").val(Expense.Amount);
                        $("#DueDate").val(Expense.DueDate);
                        $("#Date").val(Expense.Date);
                        $("#Date").val(Expense.Date);
                        Classif = Expense.ClassificationsID;
                        Subclassif = Expense.SubclassificationsID;


                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                });
                var a = Subclassif.ExpenseID;
            }
        </script>
```

Does not respond to call to function
This is the error I get at f12
Expense-table.aspx:13072 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: please try adding a comma between the values and remove the variable name. Like this:

  <button type="button" class="btn tblActnBtn" onclick="javascript:UpdateExpnse(<%#Eval("ExpenseID") %>, <%#Eval("CustomerID") %>)" if this doesn't work. Please look to the HTML generated for this button and add it to your question too.

Comment: `onclick="UpdateExpnse(id= <%#Eval("ExpenseID") %>  id2= <%#Eval("CustomerID") %>)" >` looks invalid on a few levels.

Comment: I really hope your aspx file isn't 13072 lines long.

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn tblActnBtn" onclick="UpdateExpnse(id=1079  id2=101)">
                                                
                                               
                                                    <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                                                </button>

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
                                                <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                                            </button>
```

This is the created html